# Hidden Figures non-scientific dialog

Tags: dialogue, hidden-figures

In *Hidden Figures*, during the section subtitled "Alan Shepard's Launch", there is some confusing dialog.  A reporter with a mic in his hand stands on the beach, in front of a chainlink fence, with the rocket launchpad in the background and excited onlookers nearby.

> Reporter:  It's a historic day here at Cape Canaveral, and here's what
>   we can expect.  Alan Shepard and Freedom 7 will be launched into space
>   at **an altitude of about 116 miles an hour.**

The last part of the quote makes no sense. Altitudes are measured in miles, not miles an hour. I'm trying to figure out why that was included in a movie that seemed to treat physics and mathematics pretty seriously.

- Was this something a reporter of the time actually said?
- Was the line written this way to insinuate that reporters didn't understand the science they were talking about?
- Was this line improvised by the actor who played the reporter?
- Was this really just bad writing?

Comment: It's just a stupid mistake, and no reporter will ever ask the makers of the movie about how such an insignificant blunder came to pass.

Comment: Interesting that the dialogue does not appear in the [script](http://s3.foxmovies.com/foxmovies/production/films/123/assets/hidden_figures_screenplay.pdf-5183735384.pdf) which would leave one to believe it a late insert that just hap[ens to contain a blunder.

Comment: Downvoter: why?

Comment: Probably because the answer can be found in the trivia section of IMDB and it's the 7th hit when you google *launched into space at an altitude of about*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a goof, probably on the part of the actor. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4846340/goofs?item=gf3247322